# Sort an array of hashes

Tags: perl, sorting, reference

I have a reference that has the following data structure when dumped:

```
VAR1 = [
          {
            '0'  => 0
          },
          {
            '1'  => 1
          },
          {
            '-1' => 2
          },
          {
            '2'  => 3
          },
];
```

I am trying to loop over them and eventually sort by key. Here is an example of my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $skew_ref;
push @{$skew_ref}, { 0 => 0, 1 => 1, -1 => 2, 2 => 3, };

my @sorted;
for my $ref ( @{$skew_ref} ) {
    while ( my ($k, $v ) = each %{$ref} ) {
        print "$k => $v\n";
    }
    @sorted = sort { %{$b} <=> %{$a} } keys %{$ref};
}

print Dumper(\@sorted);
```

What am I doing incorrectly? I want the smallest key value and it is giving me the largest.

The output should just be `2` in this case.

Comment: What do you think `%{$a}` produces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use List::Util qw( min );

my $skews = { 0 => 0, 1 => 1, -1 => 2, 2 => 3 };

my $val = $skews->{ min keys %$skews };
```

Contrary to your implications, there cannot be more than one result since a hash cannot have two elements with the same key.

Comment: Nice, Thanks. I need to just paste a note to my screen: `use List::Util;`

Answer (score 1):

Answering your direct question: you swapped `a` and `b` in the sort closure:

```
@sorted = sort { %{$a} <=> %{$b} } keys %{$ref};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my @sorted = map $_->[0], 
  sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } 
  map [ $_, keys %$_ ], @arr;
```

Comment: His question is misleading. If you look carefully, he appears to start with a hash, not an array of hashes, so your solution uses 3 `map`, but I showed that only one is needed.

Comment: It's clear he starts with `{ 0 => 0, 1 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3, }`, though.

Comment: @ikegami - no, he has an array of hashes, as given by the Dump at the start of the question.  After that things get muddy.

Comment: Is that considered the schwartzian transform?

Comment: @Mark Reed, No, that's the *output* of his program. You can even see the call to `Dumper`. But while that's the output he *has*, that's not the output he *wants*. The only thing that's unclear is the output he wants (since he didn't specify it).

Comment: @perlsufi yes, it is widely known by this name.

Comment: @perlsufi, yes, it's an ST, but it makes no sense to use it here.

Comment: (It does extra work to compensate for needless extra work already done.)

Comment: @ikegami, Apologies. I have updated my original post for the specific output I want.

Comment: @ikegami, sorry again- I put in the post that want in this case is technically just '2' ( because the key is -1 ). The specific output was less important to me than figuring out how to sort the structure :/

Comment: @perlsufi, No sorting is required. See my answer.